# Best practice to handle null props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null, default-value

Consider I got two components:

```js
// Hello.js

import React from "react";

export default function Hello(props) {
  const { name = "mike" } = props;
  return <div>Hello {name}</div>;
}
```

```js
// App.js

import React from "react";
import Hello from "./Hello";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Hello name={null} />
    </div>
  );
}

// renders Hello
```

If I pass `null` props to the `Hello` component, The `Hello` component will not use the default value, instead, it will just use `null` as a value and render it.

The default value will only be used when i explicitly pass `undefined` or not pass anything:

```js
<Hello name={undefined} />
<Hello />

// renders Hello mike
```

So my question is How should i handle null props correctly? Should i handle it in parent component when pass it to child component like this:

```js
// App.js
<Hello name={getName() || 'mike'} />
```

Or i should handle it in child component like this:

```js
// Hello.js

return <div>Hello {name || "mike"}</div>;
```

Is there any "best practice" to help handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bad, cos somebody else will forget and yell WTF

```
// App.js
<Hello name={getName() || 'mike'} />
```

so so, but this is ugly, assign default value is more elegant

```
// Hello.js
return <div>Hello {name || "mike"}</div>;
```

better, why not just return string or undefined

```
function getName(){
  ...
  return something || undefined
}
```

best,  people wont always do so, how to make sure? TypeScript will check it when compile

```
interface Props {
    name: string;
}
interface State {
    xxx: xxx
}
class Hello extends React.Component<Props, State> {
```

choose as you like, cos best costs most

Answer (score 2):

You can use JS null coalescing operator to achieve in a below way:

```
props.name ?? 'Default value'
```